# Marker-like functionality in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Are there any plugins for Gazebo that provide functionality similar to the Marker plugin for rviz? If not, I'll look into creating a visual plugin that wraps the DynamicLines class to support ROS nodes creating dynamic and generic geometric visualizations.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14518/marker-like-functionality-in-gazebo/) by [sandytf](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2847/sandytf/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-09-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Visual markers have been added to gazebo8. Use `gz marker -h` for help.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2017-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0